# how to update a json data in sql threw php

Tags: php, sql, json, codeigniter

i am working on a form which i have to insert a data in sql in Json format .
Insert is complete.now the problem is update.

This is my Update model in codeigniter:

```
public function Update()
            {
                print("<pre>");
                    print_r($_POST);
                    print_r($_REQUEST['Userid']);
                    print("</pre>");
                $jsonData = json_encode($_POST);
                $data2 = array(

                    'form_data' => $jsonData
                );


                $this->db->where($_REQUEST['Userid']);
                $this->db->update('form',$data2);
                return;
            }
```

my sql table has two field: (1) id  (2) form 
in form i store all form data in json format. i get data on the form page but it didn't update.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where($_REQUEST['Userid']);
```

should instead be

```
$this->db->where('id',$_REQUEST['Userid']);`
```

You are missing the `column` parameter in your `where` clause